Error while creating database using sqflite, flutter. Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Error Domain=SqfliteDarwinDatabase Code=1 "no such table:
I am building my app using sqflite, but I cannot resolve an following error:
Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Error Domain=SqfliteDarwinDatabase Code=1 "no such table:plus"
My relating code is:
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future(() async {
    db = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'data.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) async{
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS plus(point INTEGER, goal TEXT);");
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS minus(point INTEGER, goal TEXT);");
      },
      // Set the version. This executes the onCreate function and provides a
      // path to perform database upgrades and downgrades.
      version: 1,

    );
    print("done");
  }
  );
}

...
await db.insert('plus', {
"point": Provider.of<ProvDatas>(context, listen: false).point_plus,
"goal": Provider.of<ProvDatas>(context, listen: false).text_plus});

If more detail code is needed, please let me know.

As a result, this problem was solved by uninstalling app and installing app again..!

Below is a sample code you can try that,in your code the only prblm i can find was ; in query, try to remove ; from query and if prblm still persist tell us if the prblm arise from creating the table or inserting in table
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';class SqliteService {
  Future<Database> initializeDB() async {
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    
    return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'database.db'),
      onCreate: (database, version) async {
         await database.execute( 
           "CREATE TABLE Notes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  
           description TEXT NOT NULL)",
      );
     },
     version: 1,
    );
  }
}


Thank you very much for your comment!
However, although I removed ";" from 2 queries, still same error exists..

So where does this prblm arise from insert query or while creating the db?

And please make sure that insertion is done only after creation of table. If insertion is called before creation of table it will throw same error as yours, table not found.
